# What is a size metric attached to a VARCHAR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I use VARCHAR throughout my app, and found something particularly confusing... Why do I need to define my SQL VARCHAR columns with a length, such as VARCHAR(50) or VARCHAR(1000)? Is the one and only purpose that this length constraint allows me to define my preferred maximum string length? Is there any performance difference or otherwise between VARCHAR(50) and VARCHAR(1000)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends entirely on the internals of your DBMS. For example, if you index a varchar column, you will almost certainly get a keypart set to the maximum size.

That's because indexes have to be insanely efficient and you don't want to be mucking about with variable length fields in that case, since it will probably slow you down.

Even in the data area of the database, you may find that it simply allows for the largest size. I've seen proposals that just store a pointer in the row to a on-disk-heap but that means two disk reads per row and I can't see that being a very good option for massive performance.

The sizes of your columns will affect performance with things like how many records can be read in at one time, how many can fit in a n-ary tree index node and so forth.

Comment: Interesting thought. But why would an index length depend on the underlying varchar size? I thought indexes were basically a hashtable algorithm, making them somewhat independent of the column content?

Comment: Hashing? I don't think so, at least not in the DBMS' I'm familiar with. The key size in DB2 (which uses BTrees for indexing), for example, is the sum of all columns in it plus room for the row location info. Varchars contribute their max size plus room for a length as well. DB2 allows _functional_ indexes which can be used to hash, say, a large CLOB, but that's not the default by any means since it can result in false positives when searching. These false positives have to be removed, leading to further impact.

Comment: *Some* DBMSs support hash indexes, but tree indexes are more common.

Answer (score 0):

- SQLite: Size limits are completely ignored.
- PostgreSQL: `VARCHAR(N)` is essentially equivalent to `TEXT CHECK (LENGTH(x) <= N)`.  There is no performance advantage to declaring a maximum size.
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html): Determines whether the string length is stored as one byte or two bytes.
- Oracle: Higher size limits have a [performance disadavantage](http://hrivera99.blogspot.com/2008/05/why-is-varchar2-oversizing-bad.html).
- MS SQL Server: VARCHAR columns greater than 900 bytes cannot be indexed.